# is it possible to specify the length when generate data using md5 in java

Tags: java

I want to generate the app id in java 11 code, this is the code I am using right now:

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class AppStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String uuid= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        System.out.println(uuid);
        String appId = MD5(uuid);
        System.out.println(appId);
    }

    public static String MD5(String md5) {
        try {
            java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] array = md.digest(md5.getBytes());
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
                sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the appId is a little bit too long like this `9b8388c95d1598fbe9fbcffd75c518eb`. Is it possible to make it more shorter like this `efd678efh567hg6787` and keep it unique? I can using the substring, but I am not sure it is a good way to do like this.

Comment: It wouldn't be a MD5 then, and given a MD5 is not necessarily unique, the substring is even less likely to be unique.

Comment: If you just need a 'unique' number than use java.util.Random appropriately.

Comment: Note that MD5 is no longer considered to be secure ... if you are using the hash as an anti-forgery device.   And a MD5 hash of a type 4 UUID is no more random, unique or secure than the UUID itself.